# Why does a range in an IF produce results based on the first entry?

Tags: excel

I have a column of letters (random order) going from A1 to A50. In the column next to it I want to show a `1` if any 5 results going downwards are `> 'F'`.

I'm using the calculation `=IF(A2:A6>"F",1,0)`

I would expect a `1` for the following range in column A.

So Column A holds:-

```
A
B
Z
E
T
```

However the Field where the calculation exists is showing 0. I would expect a 1 as "Z" and "T" are both greater than "F".

So firstly what am I doing wrong and secondly why does the `IF` statement behave in that manner and not the way I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF by itself is not designed to do what you think it should.

You can do it two ways, Either wrap the condition in OR and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode to make an array formula:

```
=IF(OR(A2:A6>"F"),1,0)
```

Or use COUNTIF and enter normally:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,">"&"F"),1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason not to use `COUNTIF(A:A,">F")`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad no, but I find it easier for here so the OP can see that they can replace the `"F"` with a cell and not change anything else.  Inevitably when I do it your way I get the question, "How do I use a cell instead of the string?".  So I always assume that this is a test and they are going to expound in their own sheets.  Otherwise I would have recommended simply `=--OR(A2:A6>"F")` as an array formula.  Or `=--(COUNTIF(A:A,">F")>0)` which will return the `1` or `0` without the need for the IF at all.  But I assume the user will replace the `1` and `0` with something else.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question perfectly. I come from a programming background so it just appeared wrong. Is there a reason why the second part of the range does nothing? It's almost like it is bugged from the way it works.

Comment: The problem is that `=IF(A2:A6>"F",1,0)` entered as an array formula will technically work, but it will return an array not a single value.  You would need to array enter the formula into a range of cells the same size and shape as the condition and you will get 5 cells in a column filled like this {0,0,1,0,1}  You could wrap the IF in MAX: `=MAX(IF(A2:A6>"F",1,0))` and get the `1` or `0` you want, but you need to tell Excel how to interpret the array that gets returned. @AlanRaby.  Also do not forget to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Explains perfectly. Also checked the er..check to mark as answered. Thanks again.